# Relacionar partes de un mapa SVG con una tabla

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svg

Quiero saber si es posible la interacción de que al momento de que el evento hover ocurra en la tabla también afecte a ese mismo municipio en el mapa o alguna forma de dar esa impresión.

[image: Vista del mapa y lista de municipios]

la tabla la genero así después de consultar los datos con un AJAX:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el mapa es una imagen svg que hice en illustrator en el código se ve así(además de la etiqueta path también algunos salen con la etiqueta polygon):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Cómo andas, Esteban?

Veo que el `id` de los gráficos de los municipios coinciden con el nombre del municipio pero separados con `'_'`

Cuando creas cada fila de la tabla podés agregarles los eventos `onmouseover` y `onmouseout` con una función que active/desactive un efecto en tu gráfico:

```
tableBody.innerHTML += `<tr>${Municipio + hombre + mujer + indeterminado + total}</tr>`;

// Cambio los espacios por '_'
let id_Municipio = response[i].replace(/\s/g, '_');

// Agregamos el efecto de hover que va a afectar al gráfico
tableBody.addEventListener('mouseover', () => resaltar(id_Municipio)); // mouse encima
tableBody.addEventListener('mouseout' , () => apagar(id_Municipio)); // mouse afuera
```

Las funciones `resaltar(id)` y `apagar(id)` :

```
function resaltar(id_Municipio) {
    const grafico_muni = document.querySelector(`#mapasvg #${id_Municipio} path`);
    if (grafico_muni) {
        grafico_muni.classList.add('activa');
    }
}

function apagar ( id_Municipio : string ) {
    const grafico_muni = document.querySelector(`#mapasvg #${id_Municipio} path`);
    if (grafico_muni) {
        grafico_muni.classList.remove('activa');
    }
}
```

Tendrías que crear en tu css `.activa` según cómo quieras que se vea tu municipio cuando esté resaltado :

```
// Para probar vamos a rellenarlo con rojo
.activa {
    fill : red;
}
```

Espero que le encuentres la vuelta ! Se ve interesante el trabajo